# How can make an image up of screen?

Tags: css, lightbox

I use the lightbox control (http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/  ) to display an image.
It's Ok, but the displayed image is closed the bottom of screen, I hope to make the image to close the top of screen, how can I do ? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a `top:0px` in `#jquery-lightbox` under `jquery.lightbox-0.5.css`

**For Instance,**

```
#jquery-lightbox {top:0px;}
```

Comment: Sorry, #jquery-lightbox {top:0px;} don't work, you can test it at https://www.dropbox.com/s/ty4uimjdtn61p11/lightbox.zip

Comment: add !important. For Instance, `#jquery-lightbox {top:0px !important;}` - @user828896